# How to bold value in one column if value in another column of the same row is NA?

Tags: r

I am trying to bold the value in one column if the value in the column next to it is NA. This is what I have tried to far

```
\[if (SA \<-SA\[!is.na(SA\[ ,4\]) , \]
style = list(
cell_text(weight = "bold")
)
location = cells_body(
columns = 3,
row = is.na(SA\[,4\])
))
```

Comment: Please provide more context. The best would be to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4821142). It looks like you are using the `gt` package here? This is information you should include in your question.